# how to Make a sqlite3 database in python with 1 row

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

I was wondering if there is way to make a sqlite3 database in python with a Single row (record) of data and when i execute the code again it won't be made twice.

So far I have tried with to code:

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('db_M.db')
c = conn.cursor()
no1 = "Null"
no2 = "Null"
no3 = "Null"
value = 1
try:
    c.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS M_Memory(Name TEXT, Person TEXT, memory TEXT, value REAL)")
    if True:
        c.execute("INSERT INTO M_Memory(Name, Person, memory, value) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)",
                  (no1, no2, no3, value))
except:
    print(" foo ")
conn.commit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i solved my own problem .. please if you have any better code share it .. thanks guys

```
import sqlite3


conn = sqlite3.connect('db_M.db')
c = conn.cursor()

c.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS M_Memory(Name TEXT, Person TEXT, memory TEXT, value REAL)")


text10 = input("what do you want to call the memory ?\n")

text11 = input("what or who the memory will be about?\n")

text12 = input("what do you want me to save in it ?\n")


def Get_The_Max_Function():
    Max_Value = []
    c.execute('SELECT MAX(value) FROM M_Memory')
    lolo = c.fetchone()
    if lolo[0] is None:
        lolo = 0
        Max_Value.insert(0, lolo)
    else:
        x = int((lolo[0]))
        Max_Value.insert(0, x)
    return Max_Value


def dynamic_data_entry(Max_Value):
    Name = text10
    Person = text11
    memory = text12
    value = Max_Value[0] + 1

    c.execute("INSERT INTO M_Memory(Name, Person, memory, value) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)",
              (Name, Person, memory, value))
    conn.commit()


dynamic_data_entry(Get_The_Max_Function())
c.close()
conn.close()
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this one:

```
c.execute("INSERT INTO M_Memory(Name, Person, memory, value)
  SELECT ?, ?, ?, ?
  EXCEPT
  SELECT Name, Person, memory, value from M_Memory",
  (no1, no2, no3, value) )
```

EXCEPT, which is MINUS in other databases (such as Oracle), makes sure the row will not not be inserted if another row is already there with all values equal.

Comment: what does   EXCEPT means ? is that try: and except: ?

Comment: also how will i select a 4 values from M_Memory when i didn't make the database yet .. my Question is that we want to insert a single row for the first time in the database .. then it wont be inserted again ..